# soft question: How do I do a long division sign and then carry out calculations using the code?

Tags: support

I am working with rational functions and I want to ask a question that revolves around dividing rational functions for integration but I have no idea how to set up the question and show my work

Comment: See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21096/167548).

Comment: This site is not for discussing math. This is **Meta**.math.stackexchange.com, where we discuss site policies, and give technical support about the features of the software it is running on. You should ask this in [the main math site](http://math.stackexchange.com) instead. But, posed this way it is not a very good question. There is a reason why long division of polynomials is taught in junior high and integration of rational functions is taught in college. It's ok to have forgotten how to do that, but you should review school level books (the year depends on the curriculum.)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think we're reading the question differently. I see someone asking for Mathjax commands etc. to allow them to type up the long division process, so that it can be used in a question to be asked on the main site. Or is this also how you understand it? At any rate, it may be a moot point, because it looks like this may be [the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2119613/120540) that inspired this one.

Comment: Ah! Thanks @pjs36! A bit trigger-happy, me. That is a sign that I need to take a break lest I break something.